# How do I get formatted JSON in .NET using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, json, javascriptserializer

I am using .NET JSON parser and would like to serialize my config file so it is readable. So instead of:

```json
{"blah":"v", "blah2":"v2"}
```

I would like something nicer like:

```json
{
    "blah":"v", 
    "blah2":"v2"
}
```

My code is something like this:

```cs
using System.Web.Script.Serialization; 

var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
configSz = ser.Serialize(config);
using (var f = (TextWriter)File.CreateText(configFn))
{
    f.WriteLine(configSz);
    f.Close();
}
```

Comment: Just for reference: you're not really using "the" .NET JSON parser but rather an old parser created in the old ASP.NET days. Today there's also the new [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=net-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.8) parser that's way faster and is more considered the out-of-the-box parser to use now with .NET going forward. [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) is also another very popular JSON library for .NET.

Comment: dvdmn's answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661063/how-do-i-get-formatted-json-in-net-using-c/21407175#21407175 doesn't require to have declared types

Answer (score 328):

You are going to have a hard time accomplishing this with JavaScriptSerializer.

Try [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx).

With minor modifications from JSON.Net example

```cs
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace JsonPrettyPrint
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Product product = new Product
                {
                    Name = "Apple",
                    Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28),
                    Price = 3.99M,
                    Sizes = new[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" }
                };

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product, Formatting.Indented);
            Console.WriteLine(json);

            Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(json);
        }
    }

    internal class Product
    {
        public String[] Sizes { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public DateTime Expiry { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Results

```json
{
  "Sizes": [
    "Small",
    "Medium",
    "Large"
  ],
  "Price": 3.99,
  "Expiry": "\/Date(1230447600000-0700)\/",
  "Name": "Apple"
}
```

Documentation: **[Serialize an Object](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm)**

Comment: There's also an example of formatting json output on his blog http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-and-json-net.aspx

Comment: @Brad He showed absolutely the same code, but using a model

Comment: So the idea is just Formatting.Indented

Comment: This method also saves one from making JSON format errors.

Comment: This simple method works:

private static string GetJson<T> (T json)
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json, Formatting.Indented);
        }

Answer (score 241):

A shorter sample code for Json.Net library

```
private static string FormatJson(string json)
{
    dynamic parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parsedJson, Formatting.Indented);
}
```

Comment: You can actually take this a step further and create an extension method; make it public and change the signature to FormatJson(this string json)

Comment: There is no need for extensions

Comment: @HaseeBMir easy to say 6.5 years later, MS did not care about developers that much in the past.

Comment: Note: there's no need to cast this a `dynamic parsedJson`. You can just use `var` or `object`

Comment: @RonSijm object does complain about attributes in certain conditions. dynamic is not necessary but safer.

Comment: Seems like this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 160):

If you have a JSON string and want to "prettify" it, but don't want to serialise it to and from a known C# type then the following does the trick (using JSON.NET):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

class JsonUtil
{
    public static string JsonPrettify(string json)
    {
        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(json))
        using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader);
            var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented };
            jsonWriter.WriteToken(jsonReader);
            return stringWriter.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For only prettify a Json string this is a much proper solution than the others...

Comment: The following use cases will fail:
`JsonPrettify("null")` and `JsonPrettify("\"string\"")`

Comment: Thanks @Ekevoo, I've rolled it back to my previous version!

Comment: @DuncanSmart I love this! That version creates way fewer temporary objects. I think it it's better than the one I criticized even if those use cases worked.

Answer (score 142):

Shortest version to **prettify existing JSON:** (edit: using JSON.net)

```cs
JToken.Parse("mystring").ToString()
```

Input:

```json
{"menu": { "id": "file", "value": "File", "popup": { "menuitem": [ {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"}, {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"}, {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"} ] } }}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "menu": {
    "id": "file",
    "value": "File",
    "popup": {
      "menuitem": [
        {
          "value": "New",
          "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"
        },
        {
          "value": "Open",
          "onclick": "OpenDoc()"
        },
        {
          "value": "Close",
          "onclick": "CloseDoc()"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

To **pretty-print an object:**

```cs
JToken.FromObject(myObject).ToString()
```

Comment: This works even without knowing the structure of the json in advance. And it is the shortest answer here。

Comment: Thanks a lot, man I wasted around 2 hours to get to this solution... Can't imagine my life without @stackoverflow ...

Comment: I really prefer this one over the other answers.  Short code and effective.  Thank you

Comment: Will not work for: 
var json = @"{""dateMicrosoft"":""/Date(1526256000000)/""}";

Outputs:
{
  "dateMicrosoft": "2018-05-14T00:00:00Z"
}

Havent found a way around this.

Answer (score 66):

Oneliner using `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq`:

```
string prettyJson = JToken.Parse(uglyJsonString).ToString(Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: I agree this is the simplest API for formatting JSON using Newtonsoft

Comment: Couldn't find this in Newtonsoft.Json...maybe I have an older version.

Comment: It's in the NewtonSoft.Json.Linq namespace. I only know this because I went searching for it too.

Answer (score 57):

##### Net Core App

```
var js = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj, new JsonSerializerOptions {
             WriteIndented = true
         });
```

Comment: This answer should have more votes. Is everyone still using the .Net Framework?

Comment: this answer is respectable

Comment: Best answer here, uses the standard JSON library, no complicated code. Should be the top response

Answer (score 35):

All this can be done in one simple line:

```
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject, Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: Remember to add 'using Newtonsoft.Json'

Comment: best answer my friend.

Answer (score 28):

Here is a solution using Microsoft's [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-overview) library:

```
static string FormatJsonText(string jsonString)
{
    using var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(
        jsonString,
        new JsonDocumentOptions
        {
            AllowTrailingCommas = true
        }
    );
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    using (
        var utf8JsonWriter = new Utf8JsonWriter(
            memoryStream,
            new JsonWriterOptions
            {
                Indented = true
            }
        )
    )
    {
        doc.WriteTo(utf8JsonWriter);
    }
    return new System.Text.UTF8Encoding()
        .GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution for those who can't purchase an additional package.  Works well.

Comment: Nice one, Didn't want to add an additional package.

Answer (score 28):

### 2023 Update

For those who ask how I get formatted JSON in .NET using C# and want to see **how to use it right away** and **one-line lovers**. Here are the indented JSON string one-line codes:

There are 2 well-known JSON formatter or parsers to serialize:

### Newtonsoft Json.Net version:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObj, Formatting.Indented);
```

---

### **.Net 7 version:**

```
using System.Text.Json;

var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(yourObj, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
```

Comment: This should be upvoted more.

Answer (score 13):

You may use following standard method for getting formatted Json

*JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonWriter(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, bool ownsStream, bool indent, string indentChars)*

Only set *"indent==true"*

Try something like this

```
    public readonly DataContractJsonSerializerSettings Settings = 
            new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings
            { UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true };

    public void Keep<TValue>(TValue item, string path)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                //var currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
                //Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

                try
                {
                    using (var writer = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonWriter(
                        stream, Encoding.UTF8, true, true, "  "))
                    {
                        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(type, Settings);
                        serializer.WriteObject(writer, item);
                        writer.Flush();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    //Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Pay your attention to lines

```
    var currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    ....
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
```

For some kinds of xml-serializers you should use *InvariantCulture* to avoid exception during deserialization on the computers with different Regional settings. For example, invalid format of *double* or *DateTime* sometimes cause them.

For deserializing

```
    public TValue Revive<TValue>(string path, params object[] constructorArgs)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                //var currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
                //Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

                try
                {
                    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(type, Settings);
                    var item = (TValue) serializer.ReadObject(stream);
                    if (Equals(item, null)) throw new Exception();
                    return item;
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
                    return (TValue) Activator.CreateInstance(type, constructorArgs);
                }
                finally
                {
                    //Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return (TValue) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (TValue), constructorArgs);
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, @Makeman, have you ever reproduced serialization errors caused by different cultures? Seems like XmlJsonWriter/Reader conversions are all culture invariant.

Comment: Hello, I am not sure about XmlJsonWriter/Reader, but DataContractJsonSerializer uses Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.
Errors may occur when data have been serialized on the machine A but deserialized on the B with another regional settings.

Comment: I decompiled `DataContractJsonSerializer` in assembly `System.Runtime.Serialization v.4.0.0.0`, there is no explicit usage of `CurrentCulture`. The only usage of a culture is `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` in the base class `XmlObjectSerializer`, internal method `TryAddLineInfo`.

Comment: So, maybe it is my mistake. I will check it later. Possible, I am extrapolate this culture issue from implementation of an another serializer.

Comment: I have edited the original answer. Seems that DataContract serializers are culture independed, but you should save attention to avoid culture specific errors during serialization by another sorts of serializers. :)

Answer (score 8):

Using `System.Text.Json` set `JsonSerializerOptions.WriteIndented = true`:

```
JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true };
string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize<Type>(object, options);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
using System.Text.Json;
...
var parsedJson = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ExpandoObject>(json);
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true };
return JsonSerializer.Serialize(parsedJson, options);
```

Answer (score 2):

First I wanted to add comment under Duncan Smart post, but unfortunately I have not got enough reputation yet to leave comments. So I will try it here.

I just want to warn about side effects.

JsonTextReader internally parses json into typed JTokens and then serialises them back.

For example if your original JSON was

```json
{ "double":0.00002, "date":"\/Date(1198908717056)\/"}
```

After prettify you get

```json
{ 
    "double":2E-05,
    "date": "2007-12-29T06:11:57.056Z"
}
```

Of course both json string are equivalent and will deserialize to structurally equal objects, but if you need to preserve original string values, you need to take this into concideration

Comment: There is a great discussion about this detail here ...  https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/862   Interesting how this detail has evolved.  I learned something new about my primary json parser - Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. In case someone is looking for a VB.NET version.

```vb
@imports System
@imports System.IO
@imports Newtonsoft.Json
    
Public Shared Function JsonPrettify(ByVal json As String) As String
  Using stringReader = New StringReader(json)

    Using stringWriter = New StringWriter()
      Dim jsonReader = New JsonTextReader(stringReader)
      Dim jsonWriter = New JsonTextWriter(stringWriter) With {
          .Formatting = Formatting.Indented
      }
      jsonWriter.WriteToken(jsonReader)
      Return stringWriter.ToString()
    End Using
  End Using
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I have something very simple for this. You can put as input really any object to be converted into json with a format:

```
private static string GetJson<T> (T json)
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json, Formatting.Indented);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

.NET 5 has built in classes for handling JSON parsing, serialization, deserialization under System.Text.Json namespace. Below is an example of a serializer which converts a .NET object to a JSON string,

```
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

private string ConvertJsonString(object obj)
{
    JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
    options.WriteIndented = true; //Pretty print using indent, white space, new line, etc.
    options.NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowNamedFloatingPointLiterals; //Allow NANs
    string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj, options);
    return jsonString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JToken.Parse(yourobj.ToString()))
```

Answer (score 0):

For UTF8 encoded JSON file using .NET Core 3.1, I was finally able to use JsonDocument based upon this information from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter-and-jsondocument

```
string allLinesAsOneString = string.Empty;
string [] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename, Encoding.UTF8);
foreach(var line in lines)
    allLinesAsOneString += line;

JsonDocument jd = JsonDocument.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(allLinesAsOneString));
var writer = new Utf8JsonWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput(), new JsonWriterOptions
{
    Indented = true
});
JsonElement root = jd.RootElement;
if( root.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Object )
{
    writer.WriteStartObject();
}
foreach (var jp in root.EnumerateObject())
    jp.WriteTo(writer);
writer.WriteEndObject();

writer.Flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var formattedJson = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(myresponse, new JsonSerializerOptions
{
     WriteIndented = true
});
    Console.WriteLine(formattedJson);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Text.Json;

namespace Something.Extensions;

public static class StringExtensions
{    
    static JsonSerializerOptions defaultJsonSerializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true };
    public static string FormatJson(this string json, JsonSerializerOptions? options = default) => 
        JsonSerializer.Serialize<object>(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<object>(json ?? "{}")!, options ?? defaultJsonSerializerOptions);
}
```

usage

```
var r = @"
    
    {
    ""dsadsa"":""asdasd""
            }";
content = r.FormatJson(new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
```

use case example: unknown API response without indented response

```
var businessId = 2;
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"http://localhost:7010/Business/{businessId}");
var client = clientFactory.CreateClient();
var responseMessage = await client.SendAsync(request);
if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var r = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    content = r.FormatJson(new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
}
else
{
    throw new Exception($"!IsSuccessStatusCode:{responseMessage.StatusCode}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Serialization in .NET 9 offers more flexibility with customizable JSON output. You can now easily customize indentation characters and their size for more readable JSON files.

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    WriteIndented = true,
    IndentationSize = 4
};

string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(yourObject, options);
```