# JSON formatter in C#?

Tags: c#, json, formatting

Looking for a function that will take a `string` of Json as input and format it with line breaks and indentations. Validation would be a bonus, but isn't necessary, and I don't need to parse it into an object or anything.

Anyone know of such a library?

---

Sample input:

```
{"status":"OK", "results":[ {"types":[ "locality", "political"], "formatted_address":"New York, NY, USA", "address_components":[ {"long_name":"New York", "short_name":"New York", "types":[ "locality", "political"]}, {"long_name":"New York", "short_name":"New York", "types":[ "administrative_area_level_2", "political"]}, {"long_name":"New York", "short_name":"NY", "types":[ "administrative_area_level_1", "political"]}, {"long_name":"United States", "short_name":"US", "types":[ "country", "political"]}], "geometry":{"location":{"lat":40.7143528, "lng":-74.0059731}, "location_type":"APPROXIMATE", "viewport":{"southwest":{"lat":40.5788964, "lng":-74.2620919}, "northeast":{"lat":40.8495342, "lng":-73.7498543}}, "bounds":{"southwest":{"lat":40.4773990, "lng":-74.2590900}, "northeast":{"lat":40.9175770, "lng":-73.7002720}}}}]}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get formatted JSON in .NET using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661063/how-do-i-get-formatted-json-in-net-using-c)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

This worked for me using System.Text.Json in .Net Core 3.1

```
 public string PrettyJson(string unPrettyJson)
 {
     var options = new JsonSerializerOptions(){
         WriteIndented = true
     };

     var jsonElement = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(unPrettyJson);

     return JsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonElement, options);
 }
```

Comment: Cool! Looks like that was added in .NET Core 3.0 actually, which was released September 23, 2019

Comment: Just to note, it is recommended to use System.Text.Json over Newtonsoft now. This would be the correct implementation.

Comment: Perfect answare, works fine in net5, net6, ...

Comment: This is horribly inefficient. You are allocating objects and deserializing them to reserialize with formatting.

Comment: This may not the most efficient from a cpu/io/resource utilization standpoint. If your in a hurry, don't control the input, and not pressed for cpu cycles. this might just do in the moment and be ok for some solutions. The tradeoff, however inefficient, is not needing to know the input's structure. You will pay a price parsing an unknown type into JsonElements then to serialize it with the formatting... Will it scale? Probably more efficient ways out there. @CPerson do you have a suggestion? I am open to any solution at this point. I prefer not to maintain that solution if at all possible.

Comment: @Hunter-Orionnoir If pressed, I would use the accepted answer above. I've deferred the decision for now.

Answer (score 183):

You could also use the [Newtonsoft.Json](http://json.codeplex.com/) library for this and call SerializeObject with the Formatting.Indented enum -

```
var x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonString, Formatting.Indented);
```

Documentation: **[Serialize an Object](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm)**

---

Update -

Just tried it again.  Pretty sure this used to work - perhaps it changed in a subsequent version or perhaps i'm just imagining things.  Anyway, as per the comments below, it doesn't quite work as expected.  These do, however (just tested in linqpad).  The first one is from the comments, the 2nd one is an example i found elsewhere in SO -

```
void Main()
{
    //Example 1
    var t = "{\"x\":57,\"y\":57.0,\"z\":\"Yes\"}";
    var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(t); 
    var f = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    Console.WriteLine(f);

    //Example 2
    JToken jt = JToken.Parse(t);
    string formatted = jt.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    Console.WriteLine(formatted);

    //Example 2 in one line -
    Console.WriteLine(JToken.Parse(t).ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));
}
```

Comment: Vince - true, but if you're going to do that it probably means you're going to do other JSON stuff as well and if so it would make sense.  Even if not, I'd argue it's still better than rolling your own pretty printer in most cases as doing that requires more effort :)

Comment: This does not work. Serializing a string that is already json this way will not beautify it, even with Formatting.Indented specified. It simply quotes the string, and escapes all the existing quotes.

Comment: Ross - have you tried it?  When you use the Formatting.Indented option with it, it "pretty prints" the JSON string.

Comment: I tried the code above, and got the same (wrong) result - the fix for me was:  `var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString); var formatted = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented)`  (i.e. deserialise into a temp object, then back into json) - really not the most efficient method, but that did at least work!

Answer (score 131):

I updated the old version, now it should support unquoted values such as integers and booleans.

I refactored the previous version and got the final version:
The code is shorter and cleaner. Only require one extension method. The most important: fixed some bugs.

```
class JsonHelper
{
    private const string INDENT_STRING = "    ";
    public static string FormatJson(string str)
    {
        var indent = 0;
        var quoted = false;
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (var i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            var ch = str[i];
            switch (ch)
            {
                case '{':
                case '[':
                    sb.Append(ch);
                    if (!quoted)
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine();
                        Enumerable.Range(0, ++indent).ForEach(item => sb.Append(INDENT_STRING));
                    }
                    break;
                case '}':
                case ']':
                    if (!quoted)
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine();
                        Enumerable.Range(0, --indent).ForEach(item => sb.Append(INDENT_STRING));
                    }
                    sb.Append(ch);
                    break;
                case '"':
                    sb.Append(ch);
                    bool escaped = false;
                    var index = i;
                    while (index > 0 && str[--index] == '\\')
                        escaped = !escaped;
                    if (!escaped)
                        quoted = !quoted;
                    break;
                case ',':
                    sb.Append(ch);
                    if (!quoted)
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine();
                        Enumerable.Range(0, indent).ForEach(item => sb.Append(INDENT_STRING));
                    }
                    break;
                case ':':
                    sb.Append(ch);
                    if (!quoted)
                        sb.Append(" ");
                    break;
                default:
                    sb.Append(ch);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

static class Extensions
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> ie, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var i in ie)
        {
            action(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh.. I was looking at my old version. Oh well. Still nice :D Apparently I hadn't accepted at an answer yet, so GJ! You get the check.

Comment: Yours is nice too except one minor bug: `"url":"url('http://google.com')"` format to `"url":"url('http :  //google.com')"`. spaces are added before and after the second ":" which is wrong.

Comment: Is this one really working on unquoted values such as integers?

Comment: @JohanDanforth -- once I removed line #64 (the "if (quoted)" bit) it seems to be working fine for me with unquoted values.

Comment: why not use `.ToList()` on the `IEnumerable` instead of creating a new method? if you're using `MoreLinq` in your project, this will also support `.ForEach()` on `IEnumerable` out of the box.

Comment: Excellent! PS -- if you use this in Unity, rename Extensions to like JsonHelperExtensions (something non-conflicting)

Comment: I recommend you add `case '\r': case '\n': continue;` somewhere in your switch, as any json already with partial formatting in the form of newlines ends up looking doublespaced/wonky

Comment: Instead of having an extension method I would do:
int INDENT_SIZE = 4;
sb.Append("".PadRight(INDENT_SIZE * (++indent)));

Comment: i found two minor flaws in this code. 1st: For the indentation its better to use a lookup string[], than to generate the strings every time we have to make an indentation. 2nd : sb.Append(" "); this line appends a string and not a char, which is a minor performance difference.

Answer (score 82):

Shorter sample for json.net library.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

private static string format_json(string json)
{
    dynamic parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parsedJson, Formatting.Indented);
}
```

PS: You can wrap the formatted json text with  tag to print as it is on the html page.

Comment: Works great for me with newtonsoft.Json version 6.

Comment: Works well with newtonsoft.Json version 10.0.3. Formatted a 6MB JSON file in under 5 seconds on a Win10 Intel i7-7700 CPU (4.20Ghz).

Comment: The best answare

Answer (score 40):

Here's a compact version of a JSON beautifier.

```
private const string INDENT_STRING = "    ";

static string FormatJson(string json) {

    int indentation = 0;
    int quoteCount = 0;
    var result = 
        from ch in json
        let quotes = ch == '"' ? quoteCount++ : quoteCount
        let lineBreak = ch == ',' && quotes % 2 == 0 ? ch + Environment.NewLine +  String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(INDENT_STRING, indentation)) : null
        let openChar = ch == '{' || ch == '[' ? ch + Environment.NewLine + String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(INDENT_STRING, ++indentation)) : ch.ToString()
        let closeChar = ch == '}' || ch == ']' ? Environment.NewLine + String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(INDENT_STRING, --indentation)) + ch : ch.ToString()
        select lineBreak == null    
                    ? openChar.Length > 1 
                        ? openChar 
                        : closeChar
                    : lineBreak;

    return String.Concat(result);
}
```

Outputs:

```
 {
    "status":"OK",
     "results":[
         {
            "types":[
                 "locality",
                 "political"
            ],
             "formatted_address":"New York, NY, USA",
             "address_components":[
                 {
                    "long_name":"New York",
                     "short_name":"New York",
                     "types":[
                         "locality",
                         "political"
                    ]
                },
                 {
                    "long_name":"New York",
                     "short_name":"New York",
                     "types":[
                         "administrative_area_level_2",
                         "political"
                    ]
                },
                 {
                    "long_name":"New York",
                     "short_name":"NY",
                     "types":[
                         "administrative_area_level_1",
                         "political"
                    ]
                },
                 {
                    "long_name":"United States",
                     "short_name":"US",
                     "types":[
                         "country",
                         "political"
                    ]
                }
            ],
             "geometry":{
                "location":{
                    "lat":40.7143528,
                     "lng":-74.0059731
                },
                 "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
                 "viewport":{
                    "southwest":{
                        "lat":40.5788964,
                         "lng":-74.2620919
                    },
                     "northeast":{
                        "lat":40.8495342,
                         "lng":-73.7498543
                    }
                },
                 "bounds":{
                    "southwest":{
                        "lat":40.4773990,
                         "lng":-74.2590900
                    },
                     "northeast":{
                        "lat":40.9175770,
                         "lng":-73.7002720
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Output is off by 1 space on every other line, and it could use some space after the colons.

Comment: I can't believe @Vince_Panucio 's answer has only gotten 3 upvotes? It's pure genius. Take his linq code and paste into visual studio, then use resharper to convert  it into a method chain, to see how you'd write the same thing using normal .Select(x...).Select(y) and it's a few pages long. Well done Vince, ... very well done!

Comment: +1 for excellent craftsmanship.   
As much as I like it, for (shared) production code I'd probably split it up and convert to a foreach loop for the sake of readability/debuggability.

Comment: @mpen the extra space appears to be the space after the comma and before the quote in the original input.  So, depending on your input, ymmv.

Comment: Thanks, this is very inspiring! One minor issue is that it doesn't support escape sequences and processes braces within strings.

Comment: It's not perfect guys, feel free to fix it up in your own project

Answer (score 18):

I was very impressed by compact [JSON formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24782322/544641) by [Vince Panuccio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17211/vince-panuccio).
Here is an improved version I now use:

```cs
public static string FormatJson(string json, string indent = "  ")
{
    var indentation = 0;
    var quoteCount = 0;
    var escapeCount = 0;

    var result =
        from ch in json ?? string.Empty
        let escaped = (ch == '\\' ? escapeCount++ : escapeCount > 0 ? escapeCount-- : escapeCount) > 0
        let quotes = ch == '"' && !escaped ? quoteCount++ : quoteCount
        let unquoted = quotes % 2 == 0
        let colon = ch == ':' && unquoted ? ": " : null
        let nospace = char.IsWhiteSpace(ch) && unquoted ? string.Empty : null
        let lineBreak = ch == ',' && unquoted ? ch + Environment.NewLine + string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(indent, indentation)) : null
        let openChar = (ch == '{' || ch == '[') && unquoted ? ch + Environment.NewLine + string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(indent, ++indentation)) : ch.ToString()
        let closeChar = (ch == '}' || ch == ']') && unquoted ? Environment.NewLine + string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(indent, --indentation)) + ch : ch.ToString()
        select colon ?? nospace ?? lineBreak ?? (
            openChar.Length > 1 ? openChar : closeChar
        );

    return string.Concat(result);
}
```

It fixes the following issues:

1. Escape sequences inside strings
2. Missing spaces after colon
3. Extra spaces after commas (or elsewhere)
4. Square and curly braces inside strings
5. Doesn't fail on null input

Outputs:

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "results": [
    {
      "types": [
        "locality",
        "political"
      ],
      "formatted_address": "New York, NY, USA",
      "address_components": [
        {
          "long_name": "New York",
          "short_name": "New York",
          "types": [
            "locality",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "New York",
          "short_name": "New York",
          "types": [
            "administrative_area_level_2",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "New York",
          "short_name": "NY",
          "types": [
            "administrative_area_level_1",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "United States",
          "short_name": "US",
          "types": [
            "country",
            "political"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "geometry": {
        "location": {
          "lat": 40.7143528,
          "lng": -74.0059731
        },
        "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport": {
          "southwest": {
            "lat": 40.5788964,
            "lng": -74.2620919
          },
          "northeast": {
            "lat": 40.8495342,
            "lng": -73.7498543
          }
        },
        "bounds": {
          "southwest": {
            "lat": 40.4773990,
            "lng": -74.2590900
          },
          "northeast": {
            "lat": 40.9175770,
            "lng": -73.7002720
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution.

Comment: Best solution here.

Comment: It should be mentioned that for 1MB of json this code runs about 25 times slower than @Peter Long's solution

Answer (score 10):

All credits are to Frank Tzanabetis. However this is the shortest direct example, that also survives in case of empty string or broken original JSON string:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

    ...
    try
    {
        return JToken.Parse(jsonString).ToString(Formatting.Indented);
    }
    catch
    {
        return jsonString;
```

Answer (score 9):

There are already a bunch of great answers here that use [Newtonsoft.JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), but here's one more that uses `JObject.Parse` in combination with `ToString()`, since that hasn't been mentioned yet:

```
var jObj = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json);
var formatted = jObj.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: This should be the answer.. two lines only BUT only for the case when your variable json is a json-Object; else Parse may fail if argument is an array, string, null etc..

Answer (score 8):

Even simpler one that I just wrote:

```
public class JsonFormatter
{
    public static string Indent = "    ";

    public static string PrettyPrint(string input)
    {
        var output = new StringBuilder(input.Length * 2);
        char? quote = null;
        int depth = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<input.Length; ++i)
        {
            char ch = input[i];

            switch (ch)
            {
                case '{':
                case '[':
                    output.Append(ch);
                    if (!quote.HasValue)
                    {
                        output.AppendLine();
                        output.Append(Indent.Repeat(++depth));
                    }
                    break;
                case '}':
                case ']':
                    if (quote.HasValue)  
                        output.Append(ch);
                    else
                    {
                        output.AppendLine();
                        output.Append(Indent.Repeat(--depth));
                        output.Append(ch);
                    }
                    break;
                case '"':
                case '\'':
                    output.Append(ch);
                    if (quote.HasValue)
                    {
                        if (!output.IsEscaped(i))
                            quote = null;
                    }
                    else quote = ch;
                    break;
                case ',':
                    output.Append(ch);
                    if (!quote.HasValue)
                    {
                        output.AppendLine();
                        output.Append(Indent.Repeat(depth));
                    }
                    break;
                case ':':
                    if (quote.HasValue) output.Append(ch);
                    else output.Append(" : ");
                    break;
                default:
                    if (quote.HasValue || !char.IsWhiteSpace(ch)) 
                        output.Append(ch);
                    break;
            }
        }

        return output.ToString();
    }
}
```

Necessary extensions:

```
    public static string Repeat(this string str, int count)
    {
        return new StringBuilder().Insert(0, str, count).ToString();
    }

    public static bool IsEscaped(this string str, int index)
    {
        bool escaped = false;
        while (index > 0 && str[--index] == '\\') escaped = !escaped;
        return escaped;
    }

    public static bool IsEscaped(this StringBuilder str, int index)
    {
        return str.ToString().IsEscaped(index);
    }
```

Sample output:

```
{
    "status" : "OK",
    "results" : [
        {
            "types" : [
                "locality",
                "political"
            ],
            "formatted_address" : "New York, NY, USA",
            "address_components" : [
                {
                    "long_name" : "New York",
                    "short_name" : "New York",
                    "types" : [
                        "locality",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name" : "New York",
                    "short_name" : "New York",
                    "types" : [
                        "administrative_area_level_2",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name" : "New York",
                    "short_name" : "NY",
                    "types" : [
                        "administrative_area_level_1",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name" : "United States",
                    "short_name" : "US",
                    "types" : [
                        "country",
                        "political"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "geometry" : {
                "location" : {
                    "lat" : 40.7143528,
                    "lng" : -74.0059731
                },
                "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
                "viewport" : {
                    "southwest" : {
                        "lat" : 40.5788964,
                        "lng" : -74.2620919
                    },
                    "northeast" : {
                        "lat" : 40.8495342,
                        "lng" : -73.7498543
                    }
                },
                "bounds" : {
                    "southwest" : {
                        "lat" : 40.4773990,
                        "lng" : -74.2590900
                    },
                    "northeast" : {
                        "lat" : 40.9175770,
                        "lng" : -73.7002720
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: One minor bug: `"url":"url('http://google.com')"` will be format to `"url":"url('http : //google.com')"`.

Answer (score 6):

Just use `JsonDocument` and `Utf8JsonWriter`. **No third-party library required. No target object for deserialization for `jsonString` required.**

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;

// other code ...

public string Prettify(string jsonString)
{
    using var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var document = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonString);
    var writer = new Utf8JsonWriter(stream, new JsonWriterOptions { Indented = true });
    document.WriteTo(writer);
    writer.Flush();
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: What do you think `JsonDocument.Parse` does? Surely that deserializes it?

Comment: @mpen, Ideally it shouldn't since we are not specifying the type to deserialize to. But it's possible it's deserializing it to a `dynamic` type internally. Let's hope that's not what it is doing. :)

Answer (score 4):

As [benjymous](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1073843/benjymous) pointed out, you can use [Newtonsoft.Json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) with a temporary object and deserialize/serialize.

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString); 
var formatted = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: @dvdmn allredy posted the same anwser two years ago

Answer (score 3):

The main reason of writing your own function is that JSON frameworks usually perform parsing of strings into .net types and converting them back to string, which may result in losing original strings. For example 0.0002 becomes 2E-4

I do not post my function (it's pretty same as other here) but here are the test cases

```
using System.IO;

using Newtonsoft.Json;

using NUnit.Framework;

namespace json_formatter.tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    internal class FormatterTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void CompareWithNewtonsofJson()
        {
            string file = Path.Combine(TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory, "json", "minified.txt");

            string json = File.ReadAllText(file);

            string newton = JsonPrettify(json);
            // Double space are indent symbols which newtonsoft framework uses
            string my = new Formatter("  ").Format(json);

            Assert.AreEqual(newton, my);
        }

        [Test]
        public void EmptyArrayMustNotBeFormatted()
        {
            var input = "{\"na{me\": []}";
            var expected = "{\r\n\t\"na{me\": []\r\n}";

            Assert.AreEqual(expected, new Formatter().Format(input));
        }

        [Test]
        public void EmptyObjectMustNotBeFormatted()
        {
            var input = "{\"na{me\": {}}";
            var expected = "{\r\n\t\"na{me\": {}\r\n}";

            Assert.AreEqual(expected, new Formatter().Format(input));
        }

        [Test]
        public void MustAddLinebreakAfterBraces()
        {
            var input = "{\"name\": \"value\"}";
            var expected = "{\r\n\t\"name\": \"value\"\r\n}";

            Assert.AreEqual(expected, new Formatter().Format(input));
        }

        [Test]
        public void MustFormatNestedObject()
        {
            var input = "{\"na{me\":\"val}ue\", \"name1\": {\"name2\":\"value\"}}";
            var expected = "{\r\n\t\"na{me\": \"val}ue\",\r\n\t\"name1\": {\r\n\t\t\"name2\": \"value\"\r\n\t}\r\n}";

            Assert.AreEqual(expected, new Formatter().Format(input));
        }

        [Test]
        public void MustHandleArray()
        {
            var input = "{\"name\": \"value\", \"name2\":[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]}";
            var expected = "{\r\n\t\"name\": \"value\",\r\n\t\"name2\": [\r\n\t\t\"a\",\r\n\t\t\"b\",\r\n\t\t\"c\"\r\n\t]\r\n}";
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, new Formatter().Format(input));
        }

        [Test]
        public void MustHandleArrayOfObject()
        {
            var input = "{\"name\": \"value\", \"name2\":[{\"na{me\":\"val}ue\"}, {\"nam\\\"e2\":\"val\\\\\\\"ue\"}]}";
            var expected =
                "{\r\n\t\"name\": \"value\",\r\n\t\"name2\": [\r\n\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\"na{me\": \"val}ue\"\r\n\t\t},\r\n\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\"nam\\\"e2\": \"val\\\\\\\"ue\"\r\n\t\t}\r\n\t]\r\n}";
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, new Formatter().Format(input));
        }

        [Test]
        public void MustHandleEscapedString()
        {
            var input = "{\"na{me\":\"val}ue\", \"name1\": {\"nam\\\"e2\":\"val\\\\\\\"ue\"}}";
            var expected = "{\r\n\t\"na{me\": \"val}ue\",\r\n\t\"name1\": {\r\n\t\t\"nam\\\"e2\": \"val\\\\\\\"ue\"\r\n\t}\r\n}";
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, new Formatter().Format(input));
        }

        [Test]
        public void MustIgnoreEscapedQuotesInsideString()
        {
            var input = "{\"na{me\\\"\": \"val}ue\"}";
            var expected = "{\r\n\t\"na{me\\\"\": \"val}ue\"\r\n}";

            Assert.AreEqual(expected, new Formatter().Format(input));
        }

        [TestCase(" ")]
        [TestCase("\"")]
        [TestCase("{")]
        [TestCase("}")]
        [TestCase("[")]
        [TestCase("]")]
        [TestCase(":")]
        [TestCase(",")]
        public void MustIgnoreSpecialSymbolsInsideString(string symbol)
        {
            string input = "{\"na" + symbol + "me\": \"val" + symbol + "ue\"}";
            string expected = "{\r\n\t\"na" + symbol + "me\": \"val" + symbol + "ue\"\r\n}";

            Assert.AreEqual(expected, new Formatter().Format(input));
        }

        [Test]
        public void StringEndsWithEscapedBackslash()
        {
            var input = "{\"na{me\\\\\": \"val}ue\"}";
            var expected = "{\r\n\t\"na{me\\\\\": \"val}ue\"\r\n}";

            Assert.AreEqual(expected, new Formatter().Format(input));
        }

        private static string PrettifyUsingNewtosoft(string json)
        {
            using (var stringReader = new StringReader(json))
            using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader);
                var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter)
                                {
                                    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
                                };
                jsonWriter.WriteToken(jsonReader);
                return stringWriter.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it... somewhat.

```
public class JsonFormatter
{
    #region class members
    const string Space = " ";
    const int DefaultIndent = 0;
    const string Indent = Space + Space + Space + Space;
    static readonly string NewLine = Environment.NewLine;
    #endregion

    private enum JsonContextType
    {
        Object, Array
    }

    static void BuildIndents(int indents, StringBuilder output)
    {
        indents += DefaultIndent;
        for (; indents > 0; indents--)
            output.Append(Indent);
    }


    bool inDoubleString = false;
    bool inSingleString = false;
    bool inVariableAssignment = false;
    char prevChar = '\0';

    Stack<JsonContextType> context = new Stack<JsonContextType>();

    bool InString()
    {
        return inDoubleString || inSingleString;
    }

    public string PrettyPrint(string input)
    {
        var output = new StringBuilder(input.Length * 2);
        char c;

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            c = input[i];

            switch (c)
            {
                case '{':
                    if (!InString())
                    {
                        if (inVariableAssignment || (context.Count > 0 && context.Peek() != JsonContextType.Array))
                        {
                            output.Append(NewLine);
                            BuildIndents(context.Count, output);
                        }
                        output.Append(c);
                        context.Push(JsonContextType.Object);
                        output.Append(NewLine);
                        BuildIndents(context.Count, output);
                    }
                    else
                        output.Append(c);

                    break;

                case '}':
                    if (!InString())
                    {
                        output.Append(NewLine);
                        context.Pop();
                        BuildIndents(context.Count, output);
                        output.Append(c);
                    }
                    else
                        output.Append(c);

                    break;

                case '[':
                    output.Append(c);

                    if (!InString())
                        context.Push(JsonContextType.Array);

                    break;

                case ']':
                    if (!InString())
                    {
                        output.Append(c);
                        context.Pop();
                    }
                    else
                        output.Append(c);

                    break;

                case '=':
                    output.Append(c);
                    break;

                case ',':
                    output.Append(c);

                    if (!InString() && context.Peek() != JsonContextType.Array)
                    {
                        BuildIndents(context.Count, output);
                        output.Append(NewLine);
                        BuildIndents(context.Count, output);
                        inVariableAssignment = false;
                    }

                    break;

                case '\'':
                    if (!inDoubleString && prevChar != '\\')
                        inSingleString = !inSingleString;

                    output.Append(c);
                    break;

                case ':':
                    if (!InString())
                    {
                        inVariableAssignment = true;
                        output.Append(Space);
                        output.Append(c);
                        output.Append(Space);
                    }
                    else
                        output.Append(c);

                    break;

                case '"':
                    if (!inSingleString && prevChar != '\\')
                        inDoubleString = !inDoubleString;

                    output.Append(c);
                    break;
                case ' ':
                    if (InString())
                        output.Append(c);
                    break;

                default:
                    output.Append(c);
                    break;
            }
            prevChar = c;
        }

        return output.ToString();
    }
}
```

<del>[credit](http://weblog.cynosura.eu/post/2010/03/06/Json-Pretty-Printer.aspx)</del> [dead link]

Answer (score 2):

You need to skip `\r` and `\n` in `PrettyPrint()`. The output looks funny of there are some crlf's already present (or the source was already formatted).

Answer (score 2):

This will put each item on a new line

VB.NET

```
mytext = responseFromServer.Replace("{", vbNewLine + "{")
```

C#

```
mytext = responseFromServer.Replace("{", Environment.NewLine + "{");
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to dvdmn's answer, but when `using System.Text.Json;` instead of Newtonsoft.

```cs
string formatted = JsonSerializer.Serialize(
    JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(unformatted), 
    new JsonSerializerOptions()
    {
      WriteIndented = true
    });
```

Tested and applied in .Net6

Comment: Seems to work well. Note that `Deserialize` has multiple overloads, including one that takes the raw JSON string as input, which is probably the one most people here are after.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variant of the accepted answer that I like to use. The commented parts result in what I consider a more readable format (you would need to comment out the adjacent code to see the difference):

```
public class JsonHelper
{
    private const int INDENT_SIZE = 4;

    public static string FormatJson(string str)
    {
        str = (str ?? "").Replace("{}", @"\{\}").Replace("[]", @"\[\]");

        var inserts = new List<int[]>();
        bool quoted = false, escape = false;
        int depth = 0/*-1*/;

        for (int i = 0, N = str.Length; i < N; i++)
        {
            var chr = str[i];

            if (!escape && !quoted)
                switch (chr)
                {
                    case '{':
                    case '[':
                        inserts.Add(new[] { i, +1, 0, INDENT_SIZE * ++depth });
                        //int n = (i == 0 || "{[,".Contains(str[i - 1])) ? 0 : -1;
                        //inserts.Add(new[] { i, n, INDENT_SIZE * ++depth * -n, INDENT_SIZE - 1 });
                        break;
                    case ',':
                        inserts.Add(new[] { i, +1, 0, INDENT_SIZE * depth });
                        //inserts.Add(new[] { i, -1, INDENT_SIZE * depth, INDENT_SIZE - 1 });
                        break;
                    case '}':
                    case ']':
                        inserts.Add(new[] { i, -1, INDENT_SIZE * --depth, 0 });
                        //inserts.Add(new[] { i, -1, INDENT_SIZE * depth--, 0 });
                        break;
                    case ':':
                        inserts.Add(new[] { i, 0, 1, 1 });
                        break;
                }

            quoted = (chr == '"') ? !quoted : quoted;
            escape = (chr == '\\') ? !escape : false;
        }

        if (inserts.Count > 0)
        {
            var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(str.Length * 2);

            int lastIndex = 0;
            foreach (var insert in inserts)
            {
                int index = insert[0], before = insert[2], after = insert[3];
                bool nlBefore = (insert[1] == -1), nlAfter = (insert[1] == +1);

                sb.Append(str.Substring(lastIndex, index - lastIndex));

                if (nlBefore) sb.AppendLine();
                if (before > 0) sb.Append(new String(' ', before));

                sb.Append(str[index]);

                if (nlAfter) sb.AppendLine();
                if (after > 0) sb.Append(new String(' ', after));

                lastIndex = index + 1;
            }

            str = sb.ToString();
        }

        return str.Replace(@"\{\}", "{}").Replace(@"\[\]", "[]");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
    public static string JsonFormatter(string json)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        bool quotes = false;

        bool ignore = false;

        int offset = 0;

        int position = 0;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        json = json.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "").Replace("\t", "");

        foreach (char character in json)
        {
            switch (character)
            {
                case '"':
                    if (!ignore)
                    {
                        quotes = !quotes;
                    }
                    break;
                case '\'':
                    if (quotes)
                    {
                        ignore = !ignore;
                    }
                    break;
            }

            if (quotes)
            {
                builder.Append(character);
            }
            else
            {
                switch (character)
                {
                    case '{':
                    case '[':
                        builder.Append(character);
                        builder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                        builder.Append(new string(' ', ++offset * 4));
                        break;
                    case '}':
                    case ']':
                        builder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                        builder.Append(new string(' ', --offset * 4));
                        builder.Append(character);
                        break;
                    case ',':
                        builder.Append(character);
                        builder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                        builder.Append(new string(' ', offset * 4));
                        break;
                    case ':':
                        builder.Append(character);
                        builder.Append(' ');
                        break;
                    default:
                        if (character != ' ')
                        {
                            builder.Append(character);
                        }
                        break;
                }

                position++;
            }
        }

        return builder.ToString().Trim();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This version produces JSON that is more compact and in my opinion more readable since you can see more at one time.  It does this by formatting the deepest layer inline or like a compact array structure.

The code has no dependencies but is more complex.

```
{ 
  "name":"Seller", 
  "schema":"dbo",
  "CaptionFields":["Caption","Id"],
  "fields":[ 
    {"name":"Id","type":"Integer","length":"10","autoincrement":true,"nullable":false}, 
    {"name":"FirstName","type":"Text","length":"50","autoincrement":false,"nullable":false}, 
    {"name":"LastName","type":"Text","length":"50","autoincrement":false,"nullable":false}, 
    {"name":"LotName","type":"Text","length":"50","autoincrement":false,"nullable":true}, 
    {"name":"LotDetailsURL","type":"Text","length":"255","autoincrement":false,"nullable":true} 
  ]
}
```

The code follows

```
private class IndentJsonInfo
{
    public IndentJsonInfo(string prefix, char openingTag)
    {
        Prefix = prefix;
        OpeningTag = openingTag;
        Data = new List<string>();
    }
    public string Prefix;
    public char OpeningTag;
    public bool isOutputStarted;
    public List<string> Data;
}
internal static string IndentJSON(string jsonString, int startIndent = 0, int indentSpaces = 2)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonString))
        return jsonString;

    try
    {
        var jsonCache = new List<IndentJsonInfo>();
        IndentJsonInfo currentItem = null;

        var sbResult = new StringBuilder();

        int curIndex = 0;
        bool inQuotedText = false;

        var chunk = new StringBuilder();

        var saveChunk = new Action(() =>
        {
            if (chunk.Length == 0)
                return;
            if (currentItem == null)
                throw new Exception("Invalid JSON: No container.");
            currentItem.Data.Add(chunk.ToString());
            chunk = new StringBuilder();
        });

        while (curIndex < jsonString.Length)
        {
            var cChar = jsonString[curIndex];
            if (inQuotedText)
            {
                // Get the rest of quoted text.
                chunk.Append(cChar);

                // Determine if the quote is escaped.
                bool isEscaped = false;
                var excapeIndex = curIndex;
                while (excapeIndex > 0 && jsonString[--excapeIndex] == '\\') isEscaped = !isEscaped;

                if (cChar == '"' && !isEscaped)
                    inQuotedText = false;
            }
            else if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(cChar))
            {
                // Ignore all whitespace outside of quotes.
            }
            else
            {
                // Outside of Quotes.
                switch (cChar)
                {
                    case '"':
                        chunk.Append(cChar);
                        inQuotedText = true;
                        break;
                    case ',':
                        chunk.Append(cChar);
                        saveChunk();
                        break;
                    case '{':
                    case '[':
                        currentItem = new IndentJsonInfo(chunk.ToString(), cChar);
                        jsonCache.Add(currentItem);
                        chunk = new StringBuilder();
                        break;
                    case '}':
                    case ']':
                        saveChunk();
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonCache.Count; i++)
                        {
                            var item = jsonCache[i];
                            var isLast = i == jsonCache.Count - 1;
                            if (!isLast)
                            {
                                if (!item.isOutputStarted)
                                {
                                    sbResult.AppendLine(
                                        "".PadLeft((startIndent + i) * indentSpaces) +
                                        item.Prefix + item.OpeningTag);
                                    item.isOutputStarted = true;
                                }
                                var newIndentString = "".PadLeft((startIndent + i + 1) * indentSpaces);
                                foreach (var listItem in item.Data)
                                {
                                    sbResult.AppendLine(newIndentString + listItem);
                                }
                                item.Data = new List<string>();
                            }
                            else // If Last
                            {
                                if (!(
                                    (item.OpeningTag == '{' && cChar == '}') ||
                                    (item.OpeningTag == '[' && cChar == ']')
                                   ))
                                {
                                    throw new Exception("Invalid JSON: Container Mismatch, Open '" + item.OpeningTag + "', Close '" + cChar + "'.");
                                }

                                string closing = null;
                                if (item.isOutputStarted)
                                {
                                    var newIndentString = "".PadLeft((startIndent + i + 1) * indentSpaces);
                                    foreach (var listItem in item.Data)
                                    {
                                        sbResult.AppendLine(newIndentString + listItem);
                                    }
                                    closing = cChar.ToString();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    closing =
                                        item.Prefix + item.OpeningTag +
                                        String.Join("", currentItem.Data.ToArray()) +
                                        cChar;
                                }

                                jsonCache.RemoveAt(i);
                                currentItem = (jsonCache.Count > 0) ? jsonCache[jsonCache.Count - 1] : null;
                                chunk.Append(closing);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        chunk.Append(cChar);
                        break;
                }
            }
            curIndex++;
        }

        if (inQuotedText)
            throw new Exception("Invalid JSON: Incomplete Quote");
        else if (jsonCache.Count != 0)
            throw new Exception("Invalid JSON: Incomplete Structure");
        else
        {
            if (chunk.Length > 0)
                sbResult.AppendLine("".PadLeft(startIndent * indentSpaces) + chunk);
            var result = sbResult.ToString();
            return result;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;  // Comment out to return unformatted text if the format failed.
        // Invalid JSON, skip the formatting.
        return jsonString;
    }
}
```

The function allows you to specify a starting point for the indentation because I use this as part of a process that assembles very large JSON formatted backup files.