# How can I beautify JSON for display in a TextBox?

Tags: c#, json, .net

How can I beautify JSON with C#?  I want to print the result in a TextBox control.

Is it possible to use JavaScriptSerializer for this, or should I use JSON.net?  Unless I have to, I'd like to avoid deserializing the string.

Comment: You mean format it with newlines and indentation?

Comment: Could this be a possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580397/json-formatter-in-c

Comment: Do you want to format your JSON code so that it looks nice and readable? But what formatting JSON code has to do with deserialization?

Comment: yes, i'm talking about beautifying, newlines, indentation.
I do not want/need to deserialize anything, i just thaught that if i'm using JSON.Net i have to deserialize=>serialize in order to have a pretty json output.

Answer (score 57):

Bit late to this party, but you *can* beautify (or minify) Json without deserialization using Json.NET:

---

```cs
JToken parsedJson = JToken.Parse(jsonString);
var beautified = parsedJson.ToString(Formatting.Indented);
var minified = parsedJson.ToString(Formatting.None);
```

---

Edit: following up on the discussion in the comments about performance, I measured using [BenchMark.Net](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) and there is an extra allocation cost using `JToken.Parse`, and a very small increase in time taken:

[image]

[Benchmark code](https://gist.github.com/stuartd/1d156063c086f4bf214373cc109b4725)

Comment: When you parse to create a JToken, arent you create a dynamic object?

Comment: @aloisdg probably, yes.

Comment: I will have to check for performance issue. I am not sure that we are winning here.

Comment: The [docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm) say _"The absolute fastest way to read and write JSON is to use JsonTextReader/JsonTextWriter directly to manually serialize types"_ but for most use cases involving formatting Json that's not necessary, and [a lot more effort](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadingWritingJSON.htm).

Answer (score 48):

With [JSON.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) you can beautify the output with a specific formatting.

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/b4AQgB) on dotnetfiddle.

Code

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public DateTime Expiry {get; set;}
    public string[] Sizes {get; set;}
}

public void Main()
{
    Product product = new Product();
    product.Name = "Apple";
    product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
    product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small" };

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product, Formatting.None);
    Console.WriteLine(json);
    json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product, Formatting.Indented);
    Console.WriteLine(json);
}
```

Output

```
{"Name":"Apple","Expiry":"2008-12-28T00:00:00","Sizes":["Small"]}
{
  "Name": "Apple",
  "Expiry": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
  "Sizes": [
    "Small"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I assume the reason why this wasnt accepted as the answer is because, beautifying the JSON using this method would require deserialization first before re-serialization?

Comment: @Jimbo Indeed. I will check for an alternative. You can also look for stuartd [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48153713/1248177)

Answer (score 6):

You can process JSON without deserializing using the new System.Text.Json namespace, to avoid adding a dependency on json.NET.  This is admittedly not as terse as [stuartd's simple answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48153713/2308697):

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;

public static string BeautifyJson(string json)
{
    using JsonDocument document = JsonDocument.Parse(json);
    using var stream = new MemoryStream();
    using var writer = new Utf8JsonWriter(stream, new JsonWriterOptions() { Indented = true });
    document.WriteTo(writer);
    writer.Flush();
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
}
```

[The docs have more examples of how to use the low-level types in the namespace.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/write-custom-serializer-deserializer)

Answer (score 3):

ShouldSerializeContractResolver.cs

```
public class ShouldSerializeContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        public static readonly ShouldSerializeContractResolver Instance = new ShouldSerializeContractResolver();

        protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {
            JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
            return property;
        }
    }
```

```
 var beautifyJson= Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                ContractResolver = ShouldSerializeContractResolver.Instance,
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                Formatting = Formatting.Indented
            });
```

you can beautify json with above code

Comment: This is incomplete, show what is  `ShouldSerializeContractResolver`.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ridvanc/34f45923162cfd168e4c97e60439c5b8
you can see the above link

Comment: check comment again please

Answer (score 3):

```
string formattedJson = System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonNode.Parse(json).ToString();
```

Comment: This was my solution. Thanks! So simple and it turned my JSON string into a readable self-formatted display in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 well-known JSON formatter or parsers to serialize:

### Newtonsoft Json.Net version:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

dynamic parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(unPrettyJson);
var prettyJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parsedJson, Formatting.Indented);
```

---

### **.Net 7 version:**

```
using System.Text.Json;

var jsonElement = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(unPrettyJson);
var prettyJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonElement , new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
```

Comment: The .NET 7 version is not actually working when `yourObj` is a JSON string object as the result will have all the special characters like "{" encoded, while the answer bellow that use `System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonNode.Parse(json).ToString()` do it right.

Comment: @Sevenate, please see the updated version, and if it works please upvote. Happy coding...