# Can I use JSON.Stringify in code-behind of an ASP.Net project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

In the code-behind of an ASP.NET project (MVP-pattern) I get in one of the presenters a string which contains something which looks like the content of a JSON file.

Then I set one of the properties of the view - which is assigned to the presenter - with that string.

In the view the string is displayed in a TextBox, but it doesn't look good, because it is not structured with newlines and line feeds.
I know there is a JSON-function called Stringify which can make such strings pretty.

Can I call that JSON-function in code-behind?
Per example when I set the property of the view in the presenter?

So I set it in the presenter:

```
this.view.ContentAsJson = GetContentAsJson(uuid);
```

This is what I would like to do, if it's possible:

```
this.view.ContentAsJson = JSON.Stringify(GetContentAsJson(uuid));
```

`GetContentAsJson` is a function which creates and returns the JSON-string.

This is my view:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ContentJsonView.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebCenter.PP.PI.WebGui.View.FolderView.ContentJsonView" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="WebCenter.PP.Common.Domain" %>
<div id="DivContentJson" class="clearfix">
    <p>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TbContentJson" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="100%" Width="100%" />
    </p>
</div>
```

This is the property in the view which gets the string:

```
public string ContentAsJson
{
   set
   {
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
       {
            TbContentJson.Text = value;
       }
       else
       {
            TbContentJson.Text = "";
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: just post a snippet of what you have tried ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I beautify JSON for display in a TextBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178544/how-can-i-beautify-json-for-display-in-a-textbox)

Comment: Okay, i edited my Explanation and added a few examples from my project.

Comment: what does GetContentAsJson(uuid) return?

Comment: No, it's just a string variable for getting data. That data is used for creating the content of the JSON.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`JSON.stringify()` Actually converts a JavaScript object into a string, you can do it in server side like this:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
```

Edit: `JSON.stringify()` is a client side(browser) functionality. So you can't do that on the server side.

Answer (score 45):

You can use something like

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ob)
```

From library: Newtonsoft.Json

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Web.Helpers;

Json.Encode(obj)
```