# How to pass multiple keys to array in ASP Web Api?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, postman

I need to write ASP Web Api code which will take users input in this format:

```
"GenreName" : "Rock",
"Songs":[
"SongName":"Song 1",
"Length":233,
"Composer":"Composer 1"
],
[
"SongName":"Song 2",
"Length":221,
"Composer":"Composer 2"
]
```

The values are being sent with Postman using JSON. I have figured out to use string[] SongName to add list of songs, but i need to pass additional keys so all columns in SQL can be filled such as length and composer. The thing troubling me is how to place all these values into array and then loop them with foreach. Below is the code i have managed to come up so far:

```
  public void Execute(InsertDTO request)
        {
            var genre = request.GenreName;
            var datum = request.Datum;
            var trackname = request.TrackName;
            //var add = new Genre
            //{
            //    Name = genre
            //};

            //context.Genre.Add(add);

            //   int id = add.GenreId;


            var check = context.Genre.Where(x=>x.Name == request.GenreName).Count();

           // var chek2= context.Track.Where(x=>x.Name==request.Tracks.con)
         

                if (datum > DateTime.Now)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("datum ne moze biti u buducnosti");
                }
                else
                {

                    Genre g = new Genre
                    {
                        Name = genre,
                        Datum = datum

                    };

                    context.Genre.Add(g);

                    context.SaveChanges();

                var id = g.GenreId;

                foreach (var t in trackname) {

                    var pesma = t;

                    Track track = new Track
                    {
                        MediaTypeId=1,
                        GenreId = id,
                        Name=pesma
                    };

                    context.Track.Add(track);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }

                }
            }
```

**InsertDTO.cs**

```
public class InsertDTO
    {
       // public int GenreId { get; set; }
      
        public string GenreName { get; set; }

        public DateTime Datum { get; set; }

        public string[] TrackName { get; set; }
        
    }
}
```

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since your code sample doesn't show the API call, it may be hard to provide an answer.  In my experience, converting your InsertDTO model into a JSON string then passing the JSON string to the Web API is the correct move.

[Can i use JSON.Stringify in code-behind of an ASP.Net project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42343342/can-i-use-json-stringify-in-code-behind-of-an-asp-net-project)

```
var jsonStr = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(myModel);
```

Comment: What do you mean API call?

Comment: I need the logic on how to iterate through multiple arrays. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: `JavaScriptSerializer` isn't recommended for usage