# Is any ways to convert google protobuf message into json with indentation?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, indentation

I need to save **Google protobuf** IMessage object into json file, using C#.
here is sample code:

```
using (var input = File.OpenRead(protodatFile)) 
{
    string jsonString = null;
    message.MergeFrom(input); //read message from protodat file
    JsonFormatter formater = new JsonFormatter(
        new JsonFormatter.Settings(false));
    jsonString = formatter.Format(message);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(jsonFile, jsonString);
}
```

This uses the [`JsonFormatter` from the Google Protobuf library](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/json-formatter).

The problem: all json content is stored in one line. when file is quite big(>50 MB) it is hard to open/view in text editor.

What is the best way to make indented jsonFile here?

Comment: This is NOT a dupicate of the linked question. This question is specific to Google Protobuf, which has its own JSON serialization logic.

Comment: Silly this question is marked as a duplicate, when it is not.  If you are OK with a Json.Net dependency, try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48153713/459102

Answer (score 6):

As an extremely inefficient workaround, one can use Json.NET to re-format the Protobuffer Json:

```
// Re-Parse the one-line protobuf json string into an object:
object parsed = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
// Format this object as JSON with indentation:
string jsonWithIndent = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parsed, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

Since the original question asked about a 50MB file, this is probably a bad solution for such large-ish files, but given that I couldn't find anything on [JsonFormatter.Settings](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/json-formatter/settings#class_google_1_1_protobuf_1_1_json_formatter_1_1_settings), it was what I reached for.

Answer (score 3):

As of version **3.22.0** of Google.Protobuf you can use the following:

```cs
JsonFormatter formatter = new JsonFormatter(JsonFormatter.Settings.Default.WithIndentation());
output = formatter.Format(msg);
```

See here for the corresponding issue: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/pull/9391