# JSON human readable proper formatting

Tags: c#, .net, json, google-maps-api-3, yahoo-api

Hi I have a quick question regarding json responses from the web services,
I built a restful WCF service to return JSON response but the response is all messy as it a `Ilist<object>` with 60 counts. How can i format this array like google or yahoo APIs to make them easily readable e.g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not too sure why you want to format your Json response, it should be your service client which should do the formatting if required. You am look at the J[son Pretty Printer/Beautifier Library For .Net](http://www.markdavidrogers.com/oxitesample/Blog/json-pretty-printerbeautifier-library-for-net), which takes Json string as input and return a formatted Json string.

Answer (score 1):

I think no need to format it. it's very good to use compressed json. But you can still do that check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580397/json-formatter-in-c). Otherwise write in your docs that you can use some online formatter to format json. I worked with json restfull api and I prefer to use compresses json.

1. [Json formatter](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)
2. [Json tree viewer](http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/online-json-tree-viewer/)

Answer (score 1):

I post this answer because could be usefull for future users. I went into this question and finally this code solved my case.

In C# if you use [Newtonsoft library](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) you can simply serialize the JSON with indented format using one line.

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToSerialize,Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you, kind contributor from the past!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify`, the third parameter is the number of spaces to indent.

```
JSON.stringify({name: "jason"}, null, 4)
```

results:

```
{
    "name": "jason"
}
```

Comment: It's not C# but it is the correct JavaScript solution, Which is what 'I' wanted.