# How can I format JSON document in Visual Studio Community 2019?

Tags: json, visual-studio, formatting, text-formatting

I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, but it only works for *.cs files. JSON file has no errors and it isn't big, but when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> it says the command is unavailable. I tried some other combos that I've found in the internet but they don't work at all. I also don't have text editor options for JSON. Do I have to install something additionally for them to appear?

I have Visual Studio Community 2019 16.4.4 and Windows 10 x64.

Comment: is the extension of the file .json? if not, you could try to set the type of the file manually (at least in Visual Studio Code you can do that: at the bottom right of the screen)

Comment: @andre, it is a *.json file.

Answer (score 34):

If I understood your question, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> works for me.

Before formatting:
[image: before formatting]

After formatting:
[image: after formatting]

Answer (score 16):

None of the above worked for me.

Instead

```
ALT + SHIFT + F
```

did the job!

Comment: it works!! easy!! thank you

Comment: Just brings up the File menu in my Visual Studio

Comment: @nivs1978 According to the official documentation (https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf) the secuence is Shift+Alt+F (same keys but in different order from what i posted). Give it a try..

Answer (score 7):

You could copy your code into a blank JSON file using the menus. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.5.

File -->New-->File-->Web-->JSON File

[image]

[image]

Then you can right click and choose Format Document.

[image]

Comment: if web modules are not installed there won't be json file option in menu.

Comment: Funny how they want you to install web stuff despite JSON having become the default configuration format for .NET Core / 5+ (desktop) projects too... sigh

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is short key for formatting code in Visual Studio, but you need to have a web module (such as Node.js or ASP.NET) installed to format JSON.

[Modify or Installing Components in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/modify-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)

[image: Visual Studio Components]

Answer (score 1):

First CTRL+E then press key D.

Comment: This does nothing.

Comment: In VS 2022, this was the hotkey for me. Right-clicking in the document showed "Ctrl + E, D" as "Format Document".

Comment: This worked for me in VS2022 with R#2022.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still wondering which shortcut is the "correct" one, you can type "Format Document" in the search bar on VS and you can check it from there.

It even points out the path to Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022

Answer (score -1):

Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D works for me in VS2019
My file has the .json extension.
I'm using Json.Net in my project as well.

If you're having problems, there are a few packages you could import to do it through code . See:

- C# [JSON formatter in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580397/json-formatter-in-c)
- C# [How do I get formatted JSON in .NET using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661063/how-do-i-get-formatted-json-in-net-using-c)
- Unity: [Correctly Display JSON files in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61191356/correctly-display-json-files-in-visual-studio-2017)