# When serializing c# objects to json, is there a way to set different indentation settings for the objects properties?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, formatting

I am having trouble formatting my serialized C# objects using System.Text.Json.Serialization.
Here are some example objects similar to what I am serializing:

```
public class school
{
    public string school {get;set;}
    public string address {get;set;}
    public List<classroom> classes {get;set;} 
}

public class classroom
{
    public string topic {get;set;}
    public int room {get;set;}
    public List<student> students {get;set;}
} 

public class student
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public int age {get;set;}
    public double grade {get;set;}
    public List<pet>? pets {get;set;}
}

public class pet
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public string type {get;set;}
}
```

And here is the way I would like to have the json formatted:
I think I am trying to have the JsonSerializerOptions set to not WriteIndented for most of my objects, but I do want a newline for each object in an array. Basically, I want every "{" to start a new line.

```
{"school": "fake elementary", "address": "1234 Fake Ln.", "classes":[
    {"class": "history", "room": 21, "students": [
        {"name": "henry", "age": 8, "grad": 0.85, "pets": [
            {"type": "dog", "name": "kitty"}
        ]},
        {"name": "jill", "age": 9, "grad": 0.95, "pets": [
            {"type": "cat", "name": "pooch"}
        ]},
        {"name": "andy", "age": 8, "grad": 0.75},
        {"name": "mary", "age": 9, "grad": 0.85},
        {"name": "sally", "age": 8, "grad": 0.45}
    ]},
    {"class": "math", "room": 15, "students": [
        {"name": "henry", "age": 8, "grad": 0.95},
        {"name": "jill", "age": 9, "grad": 0.75},
        {"name": "andy", "age": 8, "grad": 0.45},
        {"name": "mary", "age": 9, "grad": 0.95},
        {"name": "sally", "age": 8, "grad": 0.85}
    ]}
]}
```

Unfortunately, I can either serialize the school object with or without WriteIndented and that applies to all of its objects.
Is there a way around this? I am trying to see if I need to make a converter that inherits from JsonConverter, but I haven't been able to figure this out.
Otherwise, I could just write out my serialized json without any Indentation, then modify the document to look the way I want it, but this does not seem like the right approach.

Comment: Don't think there is any support for custom whitespace. Why would you want this?

Comment: I think this question is duplicate of[JSON formatter in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580397/json-formatter-in-c)
you can check the answers.

Comment: @Charlieface, I am wanting to minimize the number of lines while maintaining readability. The actual json will have machine commands and the human operator needs to sometimes review the instructions.

Comment: @sinafayazi, I looked at this post, but it does not address my formatting issue. It doers add indentation, but it does so to all objects.
 Also, it uses Newtonsoft.Json instead of System.Text.Json.

Comment: I removed indentation, then modified the resulting json with the code below. I does not look great, but it puts newlines where I want them (but does not tab accordingly).

jsonString = jsonString.Replace("[", "[" + System.Environment.NewLine);

jsonString = jsonString.Replace("]", "]" + System.Environment.NewLine);

jsonString = jsonString.Replace("},{", "}," + System.Environment.NewLine + "{");

Comment: A custom formatter would probably be your best bet. Iterate through the unformatted JSON string while using a string builder. When you hit '{' increment an indentation index and create a new line with '\t' * the indent index, decrement on '}' etc. Play around with the algorithm until it creates the spacing you want. I think doing this kind of iteration with a string builder is easier than using the replace method.