# how to create a json format using json.net in c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I need a final json format as follows and that should be dynamic.

```
{
      "product_items" : 
      [
        { 
          "_at" : 1,                  
          "product_id" : "999"
        },     
        {
          "_at" : 2,
          "quantity" : 2.00
        },
        {
          "_delete_at" : 3       
        }
      ]
    }
```

How to create a json format as above in the code._at field is dynamic.sometimes it might be 2 and sometimes it might be 10.I dont have idea on to generate the json dynamically in c#.

```
class Test
    {
        public ProductItem[] product_items { get; set; }


        class ProductItem
        {
            public int[] _at { get; set; }
            public int[] _delete { get; set; }
            public int[] quantity { get; set; }
            public string[] product_id{get;set;}
        }
    }
```

i have create the the properties for json as above.

Comment: Please elaborate on ***code._at field is dynamic.sometimes it might be 2 and sometimes it might be 10***

Comment: now i created a json with 2 [_at] times.it will keep on changing.

Comment: You mean like `{ "_at" : 1,"_at" : 2, "_at" : 3 }`. It will be an invalid JSON

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i make formatted json in C#.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661063/how-do-i-make-formatted-json-in-c-net)

Answer (score 1):

**I'm using [Newtonsoft library](http://json.codeplex.com/)**

Your class should look more like this:

```
public class ProductItem
{
    public int _at { get; set; }
    public string product_id { get; set; }
    public double? quantity { get; set; }
    public int? _delete_at { get; set; }
}

public class ProductItemObject
{
    public List<ProductItem> product_items { get; set; }
}
```

A example on serializing :

```
List<ProductItem> list = new List<ProductItem>();   
ProductItemObject o = new ProductItemObject { product_items = list };

var item1 = new ProductItem { _at = 1, product_id = "001" };
var item2 = new ProductItem { _at = 2, quantity = 2.00 };
var item3 = new ProductItem { _delete_at = 3 };

list.Add(item1);
list.Add(item2);
list.Add(item3);


string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o, Formatting.Indented);

// json string :
//            {
//  "product_items": [
//    {
//      "_at": 1,
//      "product_id": "001",
//      "quantity": null,
//      "_delete_at": null
//    },
//    {
//      "_at": 2,
//      "product_id": null,
//      "quantity": 2.0,
//      "_delete_at": null
//    },
//    {
//      "_at": 0,
//      "product_id": null,
//      "quantity": null,
//      "_delete_at": 3
//    }
//  ]
//}
```

An alternative full dynamic that gets u the same Json string without any model :

```
var jsonObject = new JObject();
dynamic objectList = jsonObject;

objectList.product_items = new JArray() as dynamic;

dynamic item = new JObject();
item._at = 1;
item.product_id = "999";
objectList.product_items.Add(item);

item = new JObject();
item._at = 2;
item.quantity = 2.00;
objectList.product_items.Add(item);

item = new JObject();
item._delete_at = 3;
objectList.product_items.Add(item);

string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject, Formatting.Indented);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understand you properly and you just need to be able to generate that json, the product list should be dynamic with maybe anonymous classes then:

```
public class Products
{
   public Products()
   {
       product_items = new List<dynamic>();
   }
   public List<dynamic> product_items { get; set; }
}

products.product_items.Add(new { _at = 1, product_id = "999" });
```