# Is there a C# equivalent of Python's __dict__

Tags: c#, python

When trying to look at all instance attrs of a given class that has been instantiated, I could do this in python:

`myObject.__dict__` to see all key/value pairs stored for this instance.

Can this be done in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite a duplicate, so I'm not flagging it as such, but take a look at [How to get the list of properties of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-a-class). There are some good examples of how to use the `Reflection` library. For example, you can use `myObject.GetType().GetProperties()`. This only returns the properties that have at least one accessor (`get` or `set`). So, an instance with `public int num = 0` will not be included in the return, but `public int num {get; set;} = 0` will be.

`Type.GetFields()`, and `Type.GetField(string)` in the Reflection library may also be close to what you're looking for. For example:

```
Type t = typeof(myType);
FieldInfo[] arr = t.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFligs.NonPublic);
var newInstance = new myType();
foreach (FieldInfo i in arr) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(i.GetValue(newInstance));
}
```

Comment: In Python terms, I'm looking for all instance attributes. In C# terms, this would mean all properties and fields. Is there a way to show the fields too?

Comment: When I try this, for an instance that I know has many attributes and fields, I get: `System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[];`

Comment: There are also `Type.GetFields(BindingFlag)` and `Type.GetField(string)` in the Reflection library, which might be closer to `myObect.__dict__`.

Comment: but a type is not an instance of a class. If I have class `Person` and I instantiate `Bob`, the person. How could I see e.g. Bob's height, weight, birthday, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of any methods that do that specifically.  However, you can JSON encode the object and print that as a somewhat similar concept.

```
var jsonSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = jsonSerializer.Serialize(yourDictionary);
//output json
```

It might also be worthwhile to make it do a "pretty print" so it's easier to read:

[How do I get formatted JSON in .NET using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661063/how-do-i-get-formatted-json-in-net-using-c)

This uses JSON.net, but I like that better anyway:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourDictionary, Formatting.Indented);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```