# How to unescape unicode in JSON.NET

Tags: c#, unicode, json.net

I have JSON with parts in Unicode like `{ "val1": "\u003c=AA+ \u003e=AA-"}`
How can I convert this to JSON which does not have Unicode formatting?
`{"val1": "<=AA+ >=AA-"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json.NET unescapes Unicode sequences inside `JsonTextReader`, so you can adopt the same approach as is used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30329731) to *[How do I get formatted JSON in .NET using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2661063)* by [Duncan Smart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1278/duncan-smart) to reformat your JSON without unnecessary escaping by streaming directly from a `JsonTextReader` to a `JsonTextWriter` using [`JsonWriter.WriteToken(JsonReader)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_WriteToken.htm):

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    // Adapted from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30329731
    // To https://stackoverflow.com/q/2661063
    // By Duncan Smart https://stackoverflow.com/users/1278/duncan-smart

    public static string JsonPrettify(string json, Formatting formatting = Formatting.Indented)
    {
        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(json))
        using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            return JsonPrettify(stringReader, stringWriter, formatting).ToString();
        }
    }

    public static TextWriter JsonPrettify(TextReader textReader, TextWriter textWriter, Formatting formatting = Formatting.Indented)
    {
        // Let caller who allocated the the incoming readers and writers dispose them also
        // Disable date recognition since we're just reformatting
        using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(textReader) { DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None, CloseInput = false })
        using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(textWriter) { Formatting = formatting, CloseOutput = false })
        {
            jsonWriter.WriteToken(jsonReader);
        }
        return textWriter;
    }
}
```

Using this method, the following code:

```
var json = @"{ ""val1"": ""\u003c=AA+ \u003e=AA-""}";
var unescapedJson = JsonExtensions.JsonPrettify(json, Formatting.None);
Console.WriteLine("Unescaped JSON: {0}", unescapedJson);
```

Outputs

```
Unescaped JSON: {"val1":"<=AA+ >=AA-"}
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AnBcfO).

Comment: Thanks @dbc - also I found a simpler way I posted above

Answer (score -1):

I tried the following in Linqpad and it worked.

```
var s = @"{ ""val1"": ""\u003c=AA+ \u003e=AA-""}";
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(s).Dump();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this also unescapes the characters that are **required** to be escaped by the [JSON standard](https://json.org/), \ `/` `\"` `\b` `\n` `\r` `\t`, thereby generating corrupt JSON. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/AnBcfO.  The basic problem here is that you're using a regex parser to parse JSON, and the grammar, though similar, is not identical.