# Print the json content from JSON file with proper formatting into a gridviewer column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have SQL table with JSON Content. I have ID and JSON Content in SQL Table. I want the JSON content formatted well in gridview.

SQL table

```
    Id     JSONContent
   --------------------------------------------------
    1     {"ID":"201456", "Address" : "Brooklyn, NY"} 
    2     {"ID":"201457", "Address" : "Queens, NY"}
```

Desired Output (In Grid View)

```
Id   JSONContent
----------------------------------
 1      {
          "ID":"201456",
          "Address" : "Brooklyn, NY"
        }
 2 .    {
          "ID":"201457",
          "Address" : "Queens, NY"
        }
```

Comment: you can try something like string jsonString = "Your JSON string ";   

//Create a dynamic object, here you have to import Newtonsoft.Json 

dynamic dynamicObject= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);  

//Binding GridView to dynamic object   
myGrid.DataSource = dynamicObject;  
myGrid.DataBind();

Comment: What have you tried? Show us some code.

Comment: Too less information regarding your question. Please improve the quality of your question by giving relevant information to us.

Comment: Provide us with some code you wrote, so that we can infer more details of what you want to achieve and how

Comment: Edited the question with more info. -Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- First read text of file in string

`string text = File.ReadAllText(@"your json file path");`

- Deserialize it into datatable

`var rcvdData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(text);`

- Bind datatable to gridview

  `gridview.datasource =rcvdData`

Comment: This gives me the key value from JSON. I wanted the actual JSON string with the proper formatting in the grid view table. Apologies for confusion, I have edited the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do 2 things:

1. use the CellFormatting event of the datagrid. I use this link: [CellFormating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-customize-data-formatting-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control)
2. format the json for display as you want. I use this link: [How do I get formatted JSON in .NET using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661063/how-do-i-get-formatted-json-in-net-using-c). I took the one that look easy but you can read and change it. it use JSON.net but there are more options.

add the event to the datagrid

```
dataGridView1.CellFormatting +=
            new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(
            this.dataGridView1_CellFormatting);
```

add: `using JSON.net`

make the function

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, 
        System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        // Format the string.
        if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("Balance"))
        {
            // Ensure that the value is a string.
            String stringValue = e.Value as string;
            if (stringValue == null) return;

            e.Value = JToken.Parse(stringValue).ToString();
        }
    }
```